# Using xp_cmpshell with variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use `xp_cmdshell` to ping servers. I created a procedure but I have a little problem, I need to select the server IP from table that is already created.

I created a cursor to get the server IP from the table but I don't know how to use the `@ip varchar` variable with ping command.

This syntax didn't work:

```
 execute xp_cmdshell 'ping @ip'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference parameters directly within xp_cmdshell, so you have to concatenate the value when creating the command.  I recommend reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx

In your example, you would do something like:

```
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(4000);
SET @cmd = 'ping ' + @ip;
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```